# Need Criteria for following query

Tags: hibernate

```
SELECT * FROM [ScoreVersion] sv WHERE [Version_No] in (SELECT max([Version_No])
```

FROM [ScoreVersion] GROUP BY [score_id] 
HAVING [score_id]=sv.[score_id])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a `DetachedCriteria` to get you a list of `score_id, max(version_no)` pairs and do a multi-property `IN( )` with your outer `Criteria`.

```
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ScoreVersion.class);
subQuery.setProjection(
        Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("scoreId"))
        .add(Projections.max("versionNumber")
    )
);

Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(ScoreVersion.class);
criteria.add(
    Subqueries.propertiesIn(new String[] {"scoreId",  "versionNumber"}, subQuery)
);
```

The resulting SQL under the covers should look something like this:

```
select * from [ScoreVersion] where ([score_id], [Version_No]) in (
  select [score_id], max([Version_No]) from [ScoreVersion] group by [score_id]
);
```

**Prior to Hibernate 4:**

You'd have to write the query in HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(String sql);
```

Where your query is:

```
select sv from ScoreVersion sv 
where (sv.scoreId, sv.versionNumber) in (
    select sub.scoreId, max(sub.versionNumber) 
    from ScoreVersion sub 
    group by sub.scoreId
)
```

Comment: Dean Clark, I am using hibernate 3.jar, Subqueries.propertiesIn method not fount in this version.

Comment: It was added with Hibernate 4 (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6766). If you can upgrade, great... otherwise you'll need to write the query in HQL